# Array element will not show in a echo

Tags: arrays, element

For some reason one of my elements in my array has decided to vanish.  I'm not to sure why. I've started the array at 1 to skip 0. But when it prints it shows everything but 20. Heres the code anyway.

$myArray = array ( 1=> "C", "Java", "C++ ", "Objective-C", "C#", "PHP","(Visual)
                   Basic", "Python", "JavaScript", "Perl", "Ruby",
                  "PL/SQL", "Delphi/Oject pascal","Visual Basic.Net",
                 "lisp", "Pasca", "Ada", "Transact-SQL", "Logo", "NXT-G");

```
 //unset($myArray[7]);
$result = count($myArray);

         for ($i = 1; $i<count($myArray); $i++){

            if($myArray[$i] == $myArray[$i]){

              echo "<br>The language ranked #$i in popularity is ";
              echo $myArray[$i];
              if($myArray[$i] =="JavaScript" || $myArray[$i] == "C"){
                echo ", and I'm learning it!";
              }   
            }
        }
            echo "<br>The popularity of Ruby is ";
            echo array_search ("Ruby",$myArray);

            echo "<br>The 9th most popular is ";
            echo "($myArray[9])<br>";
            echo ($result);
            //echo var_dump($myArray);
?>
```

And this it what it prints:

The language ranked #1 in popularity is C, and I'm learning it!
The language ranked #2 in popularity is Java
The language ranked #3 in popularity is C++ 
The language ranked #4 in popularity is Objective-C
The language ranked #5 in popularity is C#
The language ranked #6 in popularity is PHP
The language ranked #7 in popularity is (Visual) Basic
The language ranked #8 in popularity is Python
The language ranked #9 in popularity is JavaScript, and I'm learning it!
The language ranked #10 in popularity is Perl
The language ranked #11 in popularity is Ruby
The language ranked #12 in popularity is PL/SQL
The language ranked #13 in popularity is Delphi/Oject pascal
The language ranked #14 in popularity is Visual Basic.Net
The language ranked #15 in popularity is lisp
The language ranked #16 in popularity is Pasca
The language ranked #17 in popularity is Ada
The language ranked #18 in popularity is Transact-SQL
The language ranked #19 in popularity is Logo
The popularity of Ruby is 11
The 9th most popular is (JavaScript)

So #20 is missing which is "NXT-G".

Thanks.

Comment: Change `$i<count($myarray)` to `$i<=count($myarray)` ?

Comment: Legend! Thankyou

Comment: Just a question, How come <count doesn't count the whole array? Why does the = make the difference? Sorry I'm new at this

Comment: Step through what it does on a small array of 3 things, `count()` is 3. Starts with `$i = 1`, and `1<3` so it enters the loop, prints the first thing. Increments `$i++` which is now 2. So `2<3` and it enters the loop, prints the second thing, increments `$i++` which is now 3. `3<3` fails, so it stops and doesn't print anything else. Count does count the whole array, it's built for the first index to be 0. An array of 3 things, the first three things are at offset 0, 1, 2. from the start.

Comment: Counting through a collection and getting it [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) is an extremely easy and common mistake (and sometimes a big security hole if you end up one past the end, instead of one before the end), and something to avoid by making the language do the counting and indexing for you, e.g. [PHP foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)